# Xcode Project Format: what are the differences between 3.1, 3.2, 6.3 and 8.0?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, macos, swift

When I open a project in **Xcode 9** (or previous versions) and check the File Inspector, there's a section called Project Document, with a combo box named **Project Format**.
The available options (in **Xcode 9**) are `Xcode 3.1-compatible`, `Xcode 3.2-compatible`, `Xcode 6.3-compatible`, and `Xcode 8.0-compatible`:

[image: Project Format Options]

What are the differences between those formats?

**-- UPDATE HISTORY (as of 20 May 2019) --**

I originally asked this question when **Xcode 6.4** was around.
**Xcode 6.4**'s list included `Xcode 3.1-compatible`, `Xcode 3.2-compatible` and `Xcode 6.3-compatible`, and defaulted to `Xcode 3.2-compatible`.
**Xcode 7** didn't introduce any changes.
**Xcode 8** added an `Xcode 8.0-compatible` item.
**Xcode 9** changed the default for new projects to `Xcode 8.0-compatible`. (8 Oct 2017)
**Xcode 10.2** added `Xcode 9.3-compatible`, `Xcode 10.0-compatible` (May 2019)

Comment: I found [a pull request having to do with the new project format](https://github.com/CocoaPods/Xcodeproj/pull/253) in the `CocoaPods/Xcodeproj` repo. A post from a few days ago says they haven't found what actually changed in the 6.3 format yet.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

There does not seem to be any major breaking change in this format change (I tried few of my project, nothing changed in the xml structure itself except the version parameter..).

As far as I remember, there were few project formats before that, some of which actually had major changes, but that is probably not going to happen again because that was in the times of major structural changes to iOS, like from iOS2 to iOS3.

Also, just side note, the default for new projects is still 3.2 so it is very likely that 6.3 is basically for testing and version that they will force later will be -7.

My best guess would be that the new format is there for Swift 2 and the way how modules / dependencies are handled in there, as it for sure requires some additional data to be present in the project. But to be 100% sure we would need information from somebody on the Apple Team.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Yes, like I said in my question, I noticed the default is still 3.2, that's why I got curious about the format :) So it looks like there are no major changes, though something is probably happening behind the scenes.

Comment: I am sure we will know as soon as Swift 2 is stable and released :)

Comment: Quick update: Xcode 7 and Swift 2 have been officially released, however nothing changed as to the Project Format. We might have to wait for Xcode 8... or maybe there is simply no answer to this question!

Comment: Has anyone seen any changes with the new "Xcode 8.0 compatible" option?

Comment: I see none (other than objectVersion = 48, whatever that value means)

Comment: Xcode 8.2.1 still defaults to `Xcode 3.2-compatible` on new projects.

Comment: Two years later, still nothing changed. Any new speculation, maybe with references?

Comment: Just revisited this myself with Xcode 10. Aside from incrementing `objectVersion` and updating `compatibilityVersion`, it appears a minor change was made where `LD_RUNPATH_SEARCH_PATHS` is no longer stored as a whitespace separated list, but as a comma separated collection. Still, very minor.